# Strange UIView in a UICollectionViewCell created from nib

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, nib

I have a weird view appearing inside my UICollectionViewCell subclass with a straightforward structure of 2 imageViews and 1 button.

```
final class ProfileImageCell:UICollectionViewCell {
    static var name: String { return "ProfileImageCell" }
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var anotherImageView: UIImageView!
    func setup(...) { ... } 
    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) { ... }
}
```

In setup() method I set up imageViews and pass around a few properties. I do not create any view or change self subviews.

Then in my viewcontroller I setup collectionView as usual.

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: ProfileImageCell.name, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: ProfileImageCell.name)
```

ProfileImageCell.xib

[image: xib structure]

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ProfileImageCell.name, for: indexPath) as! ProfileImageCell
    cell.setup(...)
    return cell
}
```

This is when strange things happen. I get 4 subviews in my cell. 
Even if I stop execution right after calling:

```
(lldb) po cell.subviews
▿ 4 elements
  - 0 : <UIImageView: 0x1026bac00; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x170236dc0>>
  - 1 : <UIImageView: 0x1026bade0; frame = (263 0; 112 112); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x170237160>>
  - 2 : <UIButton: 0x1026ba4d0; frame = (263 0; 112 112); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x170237140>>
  - 3 : <UIView: 0x102732cb0; frame = (0 0; 600 600); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x17444e430>; layer = <CALayer: 0x174238aa0>>
```

Anyone has any idea where does **that UIView** might come from? It has a weird frame (which doesn't change after the cell appears on screen), covering all of my cell and not letting any gestures through to the button. Also, very interestingly, why does it have a gesture recognizer?

```
(lldb) po cell.subviews[3].gestureRecognizers?.first?.description
▿ Optional<String>
  - some : "<UILongPressGestureRecognizer: 0x10271db10; state = Possible; view = <UIView 0x102732cb0>; target= <(action=_handleMenuGesture:, target=<Application.ProfileImageCell 0x1026ba790>)>>"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the `contentView` of the cell – see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewcell).

Your subviews should be added to the `contentView` rather than the cell directly, where they are currently. This has happened because your nib is a plain `UIView` which doesn't contain the `contentView` property.

What you need to do is design your nib with a `UICollectionViewCell` object, by simply dragging the appropriate object into the interface builder:

[image]

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you! Is there a proper way to setup cell in a nib for better reuse?

Comment: Yes, just remove the template `UIView` that is added automatically and drag in a **Collection View Cell** from the object library. After that you can change the properties of the cell and add other objects into the hierarchy as you would with a `UIView`.

Answer (score -1):

Create a UICollectiontion view cell with XIB file. You cannot drag and drop a UICollectionViewCell into a XIB when was created as UIView. **New Arrival collection View Cell** is a XIB but its type is UICollectionViewCell. In second image **Product Collection View Cell** is also XIB used as UICollectionViewCell but its type is UIView. Both are created in two ways.

Case 1: there is no UIView in front of our UICollectionViewCell

Case 2: there is UIView in front of our UICollectionViewCell

Make sure that your XIB is not a UIView.

[image]

[image]